# Replacing {{string}} in HTML files - the most efficient way

Tags: javascript, html, replace, brackets

I have a single-page website and on-load I need to replace all TITLE/ALT attributes according to a language set by a user. I know how to replace {{string}} with proper translation - that's not a problem. My problem is, I don't know, how to do this is the most efficient way.

Should I:

1. first remove whole BODY tree, convert to a string, replace {{}}
   and then apply translated tree to the document?
2. or do the translation on the fly, on live document?
3. any other way?

PS: I can't use any backend language to do so, because HTML templates and some elements/images within are static and backend serves only raw content (texts, images) as JSON.

Comment: Take a look at [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: The best way to do data binding and template rendering is to use one of the many well made libraries out there before reinventing the wheel: AngularJS, KnockoutJs, jQuery templates, handlbars etc

Comment: Hm, Handlebars looks fine, I think, but also, I want to learn something too ;-) Can someone explain which approach is OK and which one is not and why?